# Child element click event trigger the parent click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, dhtml

Say you have some code like this:

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div id="parentDiv" onclick="alert('parentDiv');">
         <div id="childDiv" onclick="alert('childDiv');">
         </div>   
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I don't want to trigger the `parentDiv` click event when I click on the `childDiv`, How can I do this?

**Updated**

Also, what is the execution sequence of these two event?

Comment: this is called event bubbling,A good point to start :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing

Comment: The title of this question should be "Stop child event click from trigger parent click event" It reads as the opposite.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You need to use [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G4XM4/1/)**

```
$('#childDiv').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert(event.target.id);
});​
```

[event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

> Description: Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree,
>   preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Comment: if you have 2 separate handlers for the parent and the child click events and you want to trigger only the child handler by click event on the child, you have to call the event.stopPropagation() on the childDiv, not on the parentDiv

Answer (score 25):

Without jQuery : **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/emason/1/)**

```
 <div id="parentDiv" onclick="alert('parentDiv');">
   <div id="childDiv" onclick="alert('childDiv');event.cancelBubble=true;">
     AAA
   </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Akhil It's Working for me.

Answer (score 9):

I faced the same problem and solve it by this method. 
html :

```
<div id="parentDiv">
   <div id="childDiv">
     AAA
   </div>
    BBBB
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#parentDiv").click(function(e){
   if(e.target.id=="childDiv"){
     childEvent();
   } else {
     parentEvent();
   }
 });
});

function childEvent(){
    alert("child event");
}

function parentEvent(){
    alert("paren event");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The `stopPropagation()` method stops the bubbling of an event to parent elements, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

You can use the method `event.isPropagationStopped()` to know whether this method was ever called (on that event object).

**Syntax:**

Here is the simple syntax to use this method:

```
event.stopPropagation()
```

**Example:**

```
$("div").click(function(event) {
    alert("This is : " + $(this).prop('id'));

    // Comment the following to see the difference
    event.stopPropagation();
});​
```

Answer (score 6):

**Click event Bubbles**, now what is meant by bubbling, a good point to starts is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing). 
you can use `event.stopPropagation()`, if you don't want that event should propagate further.

Also a good link to refer on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM_Client_Object_Cross-Reference/DOM_Events)