# Event onclick in <tr>

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

The problem about following code is when I click `select` tag, it triggers `<tr>` `onclick` event, how to resolve that?

```html
<table>
  <tr onclick="window.location = 'http://example.com'">
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>
      <select>
             <option>...</option>
             <option>...</option>
          </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This seems to be already asked and answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13966734/child-element-click-event-trigger-the-parent-click-event

Comment: @Soolie, that edit was totally meaningless, and your edit comment doesn't really apply to the edit. You made no change to the code and hardly fixed any of the grammatical errors in the text

Comment: @NickA Umm... Sorry mate... What I meant to do is to make the question more semantically readable. When a question is asked, people don't throw a pile of code on your face and then explain. My views. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is event bubbling. You have to make sure that the event is not bubbled up. Just add this event in the `<select>`'s `onclick` event.

```
<select onclick="event.stopPropagation(); event.stopImmediatePropagation();">
```

```html
<div onclick="console.log('Clicked DIV.');">
  <select onclick="event.stopPropagation(); event.stopImmediatePropagation();">
    <option></option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
</div>

<table>
  <tr onclick="console.log('Clicked TR.');">
    <td>
      <select onclick="event.stopPropagation(); event.stopImmediatePropagation();">
        <option></option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is the right approach, but you shouldn't need to call both `stopPropagation()` and `stopImmediatePropagation()`. Either would work in this case to prevent bubbling. The only time `stopImmediatePropagation()` is necessary is when there are more than one event listener attached to an element, which doesn't seem to be the case here.

[Check this out](https://codeplanet.io/preventdefault-vs-stoppropagation-vs-stopimmediatepropagation/) for more info.

Comment: @AdamJ Thank you so much for the link. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

---

You can use [event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) on the select element to prevents further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases.

```
<tr onclick="window.location = 'http://example.com'">
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
<td>
  <select onclick="event.stopPropagation(); ">
     <option>...</option>
     <option>...</option>
  </select>
</td>    
</tr>
```