# Parent & child .click() method

Tags: jquery, html

I have below HTML code.

```
<li class="list-group-item font-weight-bold">
    Mouse
    <img src="images/delete.png" class="delete"/>
</li>
```

I have 2 different jQuery `.click()` method. One for the `<li></li>` and another for `<img/>`.

Now when I click on `<img/>` , then  `<li></li>`  `.click()` method also running.

Here is the jQuery code.

```
$('.list-group li').click(function () {
    //some code here    
});

 $('.delete').click(function () {
    //some code here 
});
```

How can I keep them separate, so that each `.click()` method run individually ?

Comment: share your jquery code

Comment: You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13966734/child-element-click-event-trigger-the-parent-click-event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use this way:

```js
var li_onclick = function (li) {
  console.log(li);
};

var img_onclick = function (img) {
  console.log(img);
};

$(document).on('click', function (e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    li_onclick(e.target);  
  } else {
    img_onclick(e.target);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="list-group-item font-weight-bold">
    Mouse
    <img src="images/delete.png" class="delete"/>
</li>
```

Using `e.target` to check which the element was clicked. Then, checking `tagName` to classify `li` tag and `img` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Use `event.stopPropagation()` method.

This method prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event. [jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

```js
$('li.list-group-item').on('click',function(){
  console.log('LI Clicked')
})

$('img.delete').on('click',function(event){
  event.stopPropagation()
  console.log('IMG Clicked')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="list-group-item font-weight-bold">
    Mouse
    <img src="images/delete.png" class="delete"/>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have different `id` attribute on both and same class `.click`

```
<li class="list-group-item font-weight-bold click" id="this_is_li">
    Mouse
    <img src="images/delete.png" class="delete click" id="this_is_img"/>
</li>
```

When you click on element below script will let you know about that element `id` so you can use it.

```
$('.click').on('click', function(){
       var ID = $(this).attr('id'); 
       if(ID === 'this_is_li'){
           alert('you clicked on li #' +ID);
       }
       if(ID === 'this_is_img'){
           alert('you clicked on img #' +ID);
       }
});
```