# onkeyup sends parent element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem is that if I focus on the `childOfroot` element and press a key, the element triggered is it's parent yet it is supposed to be itself.

```js
function test(event, element) {
  console.log($(element).attr('id'))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="root" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="test(event, this)">
  This is changable
  <span contenteditable="true" onkeyup="test(event, this)" id="childOfroot"> | including this</span>
</span>
```

See demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/s36L8bpj/

Comment: This is similar to your question so check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13966734/child-element-click-event-trigger-the-parent-click-event

Comment: @Rory that doesn't work, unless you call the id or something like `$('id')`

Comment: Nesting of contenteditables causes weird things with events. The inside element is not going to see them.

Answer (score 0):

For those who is having the same problem, apparently you cant send the element own event if the parent element have `contenteditable="true"`.

So I changed my structure to below:

```
<span id="root" contenteditable="false" >
 <span contenteditable="true" onkeyup="test(event, this)" id="childOfroot0">This is changable
 <span contenteditable="true" onkeyup="test(event, this)" id="childOfroot1"> | including this</span>
</span>
```

Peace be upon you :)